# IOS how to read file created by other application

Tags: ios, file

In my application I have to read a file that have be created by another application on my device.
How it can be done. The file must be located on file System's root directory
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are writing for Jailbroken devices, you can't access files outside of your app's sandbox.

So, for apps distributed through the App Store, you can't do this.